# Options for reducing Protocol Buffers's Message size

Tags: java, swift, protocol-buffers, proto

I want to serialize object to data, and reduce the serialized data size as small as possible, and currently I'm testing Protocol Buffers.

I have read the [official encoding doc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding), and did some optimizations for the varint numbers, apart from this, are there any other optimizations I can do to reduce the message size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions, assuming you are using `proto3` format.

Too much size optimisation may not be worth it - these all affect the generated code and/or require knowing the range / distribution of the field values in advance.

- Use the smallest datatypes possible

  - Avoid [writing negative integers as `int32`/`int64`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#signed_integers), if a field will often be negative, encode as a `sint32`/`sint64`
  - Avoid fixed-length fields (`fixed64`, `sfixed64`, `double`, `fixed32`, `sfixed32`, `float`) if possible.
  - For varint-encoded types (`int32`, `int64`, `uint32`, `uint64`, `sint32`, `sint64`, `bool`, `enum`), the default value (0 or false) will omitted from the serialized data - use this to denote null/missing values if possible.
  - If a `bool` field is mostly `true`, invert the field's meaning to use the default value in more cases.
- Minimised size/number of embedded messages

  - Avoid nesting of messages (e.g. "wrapper" types like `Int32Value` for nullable fields) where possible - these require an extra [embedded message](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#embedded) as well as the data.
  - Field tag numbers are [written alongside data](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#structure) as `varint` - tags 1-15 occupy a byte, 16-2047 occupy 2 bytes. So reserve tags 1-15 for commonly used fields and give optional/rarely used fields higher tag numbers.
  - To visualize how much tag nesting your messages have, pipe the serialized data to `protoc --decode_raw`.
- Compress messages after serialization if you can